# If $ \Phi(G) = 1 $, then $ G = MN $ for unique minimal normal subgroup.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $ G $ is a finite group and $ N $ be a unique minimal normal subgroup of $ G $. Let $ \Phi(G) = 1 $. Why $ N $ has a complement $ M $, that is $ G = MN $ and $ M\cap N = 1 $ ?

Comment: How do you define $\Phi(G)$?

Comment: @Mirko It is Frattini subgroup of $ G $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\Phi(N)=1$, there must be a maximal subgroup $M$ of $G$ not containing $N$. Then we must have $MN=G$ since otherwise $MN$ would be a larger subgroup than $M$. Now $M \cap N \unlhd G$ (because it is normalized by both $M$ and $N$), and so $M \cap N = 1$ by minimality of $N$.

Comment: Why $ M $ is a normal subgroup ?

Comment: I never said that $M$ is a normal subgroup. In fact if $N$ is the unique minimal normal subgroup of $G$ then $M$ cannot be a normal subgroup.